# canoical way of passing knockout computed the correct observable in coffeescript

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

I'm trying to translate the following code to coffeescript as a practice

```
function StateVM() {
    var self = this;

    self.state = ko.observable("stopped");
    self.counter = ko.observable(0);
    self.timeStopped = ko.observable(new Date());
    self.timeStarted = ko.observable(new Date());
    self.currentTime = ko.observable(new Date());
    self.timeRunning = ko.computed(function(){
        var num = (self.currentTime() - self.timeStarted())/1000 >> 0;
        return (num < 0) ? 0 : num;
    });

    self.isStopped = ko.computed(function(){
        return (self.state() === "stopped");
    });

    self.isStarted = ko.computed(function(){
        return (self.state() === "running");
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
    var vm = new StateVM();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

now I have this code in coffeescript but I am running into problems with the self referentials `@` compiles into the wrong scope:

```
obs = ko.observable
cmp = ko.computed

class StateVM
    constructor: ->
        state = obs "stopped"
        counter = obs 0
        timeStopped = obs new Date
        timeStarted = obs new Date
        currentTime = obs new Date
        timeRunning = cmp -> 
            x = (@currentTime() - @timeStarted())/1000 >> 0
            x < 0 ? 0 : x

        isStopped = cmp -> @state() == "stopped"
        isStarted = cmp -> @state() == "running"

$ -> ko.applyBindings(new StateVM)
```

Is there a canonical way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... I got it working after doing some searching:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/knockoutjs/CTBLQthLGWU

I didn't do two things... one was i didn't add the `@` in the constructor declarations and another was to use the `=>` instead of `->`

```
obs = ko.observable
cmp = ko.computed

class StateVM
    constructor: ->
        @state = obs "stopped"
        @counter = obs 0
        @timeStopped = obs new Date
        @timeStarted = obs new Date
        @currentTime = obs new Date
        @timeRunning = cmp => 
            x = (@currentTime() - @timeStarted())/1000 >> 0
            x < 0 ? 0 : x

        @isStopped = cmp => @state() == "stopped"
        @isStarted = cmp => @state() == "running"
        @start = (->) ;
        @stop = (->) ;

$ -> ko.applyBindings(new StateVM)
```

Comment: Thumbs up for the question, and the answer !